# Dynamically Fill Ellipse with png/jpg image? ImageBrush not helpful, URI not working

Tags: c#, wpf, png, jpeg, imagebrush

Okay, So I have read some of the questions here, all of them with same or similar answers, I'm trying to insert an image to an ellipse from code.

```
ImageBrush ib = new ImageBrush();
        ib.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Art/image.png", UriKind.Relative));
        Sun.Fill = ib;
```

With this code nothing happens, I get black screen and lose some of the objects also.
I have altered the code, removing `UriKind`, changing it to `absolute`, to `RelativeOrAbsolute`, I have tried with `@"Art\image.png"`. All adds up to the same end.
But when I Do it In XAML, it works.
Is there a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the image file an assembly resource. This is more practical than having separate content files.

The file `image.png` should be located in a folder called `Art` in your Visual Studio Project, and it's `Build Action` (in the file's Properties) should be set to `Resource`.

Then you would use a [Resource File Pack URI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.110).aspx) to access the file:

```
ib.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Art/image.png"));
```

Comment: @Ramin Both of these codes work, I just don't get the difference between Resource and Content, so I actually don't know which to pick, I'm new to Images in wpf, would You be patient enough to explain it to me? :)

Comment: An assembly resource file is embedded into the assembly, while a content file is a separate file that is copied to the output directory, and has to be copied there during a potential application installation. For normal-sized image files, assembly resource is the better option. It's the "typical" way how image files are managed in a WPF application.

Comment: I think it is a matter of your application. This [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/silverlight_sdk/2010/09/16/content-or-resource-filesanother-way-to-load-a-static-xml-file-to-your-application/) provides an explanation.

Comment: Note that even if you have a content file, you may still load it by a Pack URI. See the *Content File Pack URIs* section in [Pack URIs in WPF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.110).aspx). So you should use a Pack URI in either case.

Comment: taken a thought, read a bit and I will use Clemens answer, simply put, for my app i need it to be in the assembly of the same, tnx Ramin for the answer, and sorry, I wish I could vote up for both answers :/

Comment: Don't worry, it is very common on StackOverflow to get more than one useful answer.

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
var d = new System.Windows.Shapes.Ellipse();
ImageBrush ib = new ImageBrush();
ib.ImageSource = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(new Uri("images/error.png", UriKind.Relative));
d.Fill = ib;

this.Content = d; // assuming the parent is a Window
```

Note two things:

1. There is an image in *images* directory named *error.png*
2. Click on the image file and from the properties window, set **Build Action** to **Content** and also set **Copy to Output Directory** to **Copy Always**.